# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't update on state change

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

May be someone can help me. I'm quite lost with this.

I'm using a ng-repeat in an Angular application to show the latest messages sent to an user, that are stored in an array (lastQueries) inside a named controller called "comunicacion":

**ng-repeat in comunicacion.html**

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="query in comunicacion.lastQueries | orderBy : 'last' : true  track by query._id ">
     {{query.subject}}
    </a>
</div>
```

When the controller detects the last messages (queries) have changed, it retrieves them again from the database using this function:

**comunicacion.js (controller)**

```
 var self = this;
 self.getLastQueries = function(){
     $http.get( API + '/com/lastQueries/' + email ).then(
            function(res) {
                      self.lastQueries = res.data ? res.data.lastQueries : [];
     });
 };
```

And everything works great like it's supposed to do. But...

**The problem**

I use **ui-router** to organize my routes (states). For example, I define this state "comunicacion" like this:

```
.state('comunicacion', {
                url:"/comunicacion",
                templateUrl: "views/comunicacion/comunicacion.html",
                controller: 'ComunicacionCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'comunicacion'
            })
```

When I navigate to another states and then go back "comunicacion", the new **changes on the array** "lastQueries" **are no longer shown** in the ng-repeat.

The changes are in the $scope, though. The $scope.$$phase is $digest when I change the array.

**Things I tried**

- `$scope.$apply` the change when I got the array from the database
- `$scope.$apply` after the change
- `$scope.$evalAsync` instead `$apply`
- Don't change the array for a new one, instead do a push of the new elements

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, especially because all goes fine when I don't change the state. I don't really know if the `ui-router` has something to do with this.

Sorry for the long question, I tried to be the most specific possible. Excuse my poor English too, it's not my first language.

The code is simplified to show only the parts relevant to the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the scope? Don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. The scope is huge, so many functions, what do you want to see? [Here](http://postimg.org/image/me5mzve99/) I show you the "lastQueries" array (3 elements, red point), the first with "Question 3" subject (blue point) and it is not in the screen (only 2 elements, Question 1 and 2)

Comment: Where you change it before applyng

Comment: Sorry, I think i didn't understand you before. I used a named controller "comunicacion". Inside the controller I do  "var self = this", so instead $scope.lastQueries I do self.lastQueries. "lastQueries" is then in $scope.comunicacion.lastQueries like you can see in the "screenshot". Can you see something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this. I'll post here the solution I found, in case this can help someone else:

Testing here and there I came to the conclusion that I was having a problem with the $scope. [ng-repeats creates his own scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes), child of the scope of the controller.

So I did the following:

Instead of declaring the function in the **controller** like this:

```
 var self = this;

 self.getLastQueries = function(){
 $http.get( API + '/com/lastQueries/' + email ).then(
        function(res) {
                  self.lastQueries = res.data ? res.data.lastQueries : [];
 });
};
```

I used the **$rootScope**:

```
 $rootScope.lastQueries = = function(){
 $http.get( API + '/com/lastQueries/' + email ).then(
        function(res) {
                  $rootScope.lastQueries = res.data ? res.data.lastQueries : [];
 });
};
```

And **initialized lastQueries** each time the controller was instantiated:

```
$rootScope.lastQueries = [];
```

So in the **html** the ng-repeat looks like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="query in lastQueries | orderBy : 'last' : true  track by query._id ">
   {{query.subject}}
  </a>
</div>
```

May be using the $rootScope isn't the most elegant way, but it solved my problem! I hope this can help someone else.

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to the `comunicacion` view you need to specify to the ui-router that you want to reload the controller.

```
<a ui-sref="comunicacion" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Comunicacion</a>
```

or in a controller or directive

```
$state.go('comunicacion', {}, {reload: true});
```

Other possibility is to return the `lastQueries` directly from your method:

```
//cominicacion.html
<div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="query in comunicacion.lastQueries() | orderBy : 'last' : true  track by query._id ">
     {{query.subject}}
    </a>
</div>

//comunication.controller.js
var self = this;
 self.getLastQueries = function(){
     return $http.get( API + '/com/lastQueries/' + email ).then(
            function(res) {
                      return res.data.lastQueries; // This should be enough as this is the success callback ;-)
     });
 };
```

Maybe the problem is the cache? Not just the browser and angular but the server too. Try to add a unique hash to your request so you are 100% sure of get fresh data ...

```
return $http.get( API + '/com/lastQueries/' + email , {
  cache: false,
  params: {
    avoidCache: Date.now().toString(16)
  }
})
```

This maybe belong to a [$http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't try this and it seems promising. I will do it now and tell you back.

Comment: I don't really know what is happening: I am in "comunicacion" state and it works fine. I send a message and (when I change the array) the view refresh to show it. But if I change the state and go back, then it doesn't work. With the change you proposed when I enter the "comunicacion" state It  now reaload and shows all the messages, but again it doesn't refresh to show the new ones. Any clues? Thank you.

Comment: At this point I am not sure and will need to debug your code but I still have one idea. Instead of setting the controller property why not just return the array from the method. I'll update the answer with the concrete imlementation

Comment: I did what you proposed about cache, as Alex Pollan said too, but it's all the same: I'm pretty sure it's not a cache problem. And about returning the array in the function, it leads to an "Infinite $digest Loop": I think because I can't bind a promise in the ng-repeat.

I'll continue checking what happens when I change states: The thing that confuses me more is that it works fine if I stay in "comunicacion" state. If I can't find another solution my last option is reload the state every time I got a new message but it's a pretty sloppy solution. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Really? Wow this is an amazing community for sure. This code is part of a big project and I cannot put it all in github public, what could I do to show you? If this is problematic don't worry, I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are loading your scope is making the changing of `self` not update the scope itself. Try changing self.lastQueries to a direct change of the $scope and see if that solves it. I think it will.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I tried that too but it was the same. Anyway when I log the $scope I can see the array and the changes, but they doesn't show on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a cache issue. Try disabling the cache:

```
$http.get( API + '/com/lastQueries/' + email, {cache: false}).then(
        function(res) {
                  self.lastQueries = res.data ? res.data.lastQueries : [];
 });
```

If it works then create a better mechanism to control the cache (it is not a good idea to disable the cache). See

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

and

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache

Comment: Thank you, I thought that too. But I set Cache-Control:no-cache for that resource on the server side, tried disabling the cache on the browser... and seems that is not the problem. Thaks for the idea anyway.

Comment: anyway try the code {cache: false}. AngularJs has its own cache mechanism independent from browser's.